# Is it possible to have less +F with lesskey's that work without interrupt?

Tags: less

My situation is that I currently have some `lesskey`s set.

And they do things fine in normal mode, but I want to have the file that I'm view also be updated.

This is obviously possible with `less +F`, except for the fact that it "breaks" the `lesskey`s.
By "breaks" I mean I have to hit the interrupt, and then I'm able to do the things I set `lesskey` to do. But I don't *want* to have to hit the interrupt.

Any suggestions?

---

If you want specifics, I'm using [iil](http://chiselapp.com/user/onys/repository/iil/home), and want it to work with `+F` without me having to hit `^C` every time I want to do something.